# Simple webpage change or button removed and scraped data is useless

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I'm encoutering a lot of pages which breaks the scrape with a simple button remove or even just a minor glitch in the page.

This problem appears to pop up a lot, but I am unsure how to get around it.  In essence, as the team, odds and whatever have disappeared, it gets the xpath with the link: `(    //*[contains(@class, "sport-block") and .//div/div]//*[contains(@class, "purple-ar")])`.  As it is supposed to but not the team and odds creating a useless scrape.

I originally used CSS selectors but I cannot think of how this would be possible with limitations of CSS.

Simple xpath I am after:

```
//*[contains(@class, "sport-block") and .//div/div]//*[contains(@class, "purple-ar")]
```

Problem still remains.

I'm not super familiar with ancestors and preceding... But something like xpath:

i.e: `//a/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'xpath')]/preceding-sibling::div[contains(@class, 'xpath')]//a`

to:

```
//a/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'table-grid')]/preceding-sibling::span[contains(@class, 'sprite-icon arrow-icon arrow-right arrow-purple')]//a
```

May solve (assuming I can get this to work).

```
                        <td class="top-subheader uppercase">
                            <span>
                                English Premier League Futures
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="content">
                            <div class="titles">
                                <span class="match-name">
                                                                                <a href="/sports-betting/soccer/united-kingdom/english-premier-league-futures/outright-markets-20171226-616961-22079860">
                                            Outright Markets
                                        </a>
                                                                        </span>
                                <span class="tv">
                                                                                26/12

                                                                        </span>

                                                                        <span class="other-matches">
                                        <a href="/sports-betting/soccer/united-kingdom/english-premier-league-futures/outright-markets-20171226-616961-22079860" class="purple-arrow">5 Markets
                                            <span class="sprite-icon arrow-icon arrow-right arrow-purple"></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </span>
```

Any ideas how I can get around this issue?  Thanks.

Current output:

```
Steaua Bucharest    Link for below
Celtic  Link for below
Napoli  Link for below
Lyon    Link for below
```

Desired:

```
Steaua Bucharest    LINK FOR Steaua Bucharest
Celtic  Link Celtic
Napoli  Link for Napoli
Lyon    Link for Lyon
```

[image]

Any ideas how I can get around this? Or even narrowed down approach? Persistent issue. Thanks.

Comment: `'xpath'` as in **//a/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'xpath')]/preceding-sibling::div[contains(@class, 'xpath')]//a** is not a xpath, its a `Attribute Value`. What is your exact manual step which you are trying to Automate?

Comment: @DebanjanB I'm trying to adjust the xpath so the scrape output is not uneven here is my full code: https://pastebin.com/qBxe38Cy .  I had used css: .match-name a but I'm not sure this output issue is resolvable in css.

Comment: @DebanjanB I am not very familiar with this approach.  Never really had to use it but turns out if a table goes missing or page changes just a little, scraping data turns out to move a column down

Comment: Can you be more precise about the Output you are looking for? Is using `Selenium` mandatory for you?

Comment: @DebanjanB Provided a general example to illustrate what is happening and data appearance shows what output looks like highlighted.  I'd like to stick to using Selenium where possible.

Comment: it's not really clear what are you asking ... you can't find the element by Xpath, right?

Comment: So content is the page's HTML, ok. Which XPATH **query** is not working as expected?

Comment: See updates above

Comment: I see that you have posted HTML of a row that has a glitch. Can you post html of a row that does not have a problem

Answer (score 4):

To ensure that your data structures are intact for each group, I iterated through them and used nested (or relative? I'm not sure of the terms here) XPaths to grab the data. Relative XPaths can be used by putting a `.` before each query.

I also cleaned up a bit:

- You grabbed a bunch of links and used them to iterate through the pages until completed. I replaced that with a while loop.
- I added plenty of try / except to catch as much data as possible.
- I added a sleep on each new page to allow for the data to load (timing can be adjusted manually based on your network connection).

Let me know if this solves your data consistency issues.

```
import csv
import os
import time
from random import shuffle
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://crownbet.com.au/sports-betting/soccer')

header = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('header')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].hidden="true";', header)
header1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.row.no-margin.nav.sticky-top-nav')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].hidden="true";', header1)

# XPaths for the data
groups = '//div[@id="sports-matches"]/div[@class="container-fluid"]'
xp_match_link = './/span[@class="match-name"]/a'
xp_bp1 = './/div[@data-id="1"]//span[@class="bet-party"]'
xp_ba1 = './/div[@data-id="3"]//span[@class="bet-amount"]'
xp_bp3 = './/div[@data-id="3"]//span[@class="bet-party"]'
xp_ba3 = './/div[@data-id="3"]//span[@class="bet-amount"]'

while True:
    try:
        # wait for the data to populate the tables
        wait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, (xp_bp1))))
        time.sleep(2)

        data = []
        for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(groups):
            try:
                match_link = elem.find_element_by_xpath(xp_match_link)\
                    .get_attribute('href')
            except:
                match_link = None

            try:
                bp1 = elem.find_element_by_xpath(xp_bp1).text
            except:
                bp1 = None

            try:
                ba1 = elem.find_element_by_xpath(xp_ba1).text
            except:
                ba1 = None

            try:
                bp3 = elem.find_element_by_xpath(xp_bp3).text
            except:
                bp3 = None

            try:
                ba3 = elem.find_element_by_xpath(xp_ba3).text
            except:
                ba3 = None

            data.append([match_link, bp1, ba1, bp3, ba3])
        print(data)

        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Next Page"]')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
        wait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Next Page"]')))
        element.click()

        with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            for row in data:
                writer.writerow(row)

    except TimeoutException as ex:
        pass
    except NoSuchElementException as ex:
        print(ex)
        break
```

Comment: Is there an approach that relies on css?  The xpaths can get quite lengthy & finicky if even slightly off i.e //*[@id='sports-matches']/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2].   The original pastebin has recently expired, this is indefinite.  https://pastebin.com/3aaC3ZiX

Comment: @user9099 why do you need this in CSS? What are you trying to accomplish? It looks like your identifying groups of data. Identifying the data within the groups is handled in the script I posted. It's denoted within the variable `groups`. The sub querying of each group prefixes `.` before each query, so `xp_match_link`, `xp_bp1`, etc. all contain sub queries of each group.