# Dealing with uneven data

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

How do I deal with page that are bugged so data is not scraped correctly similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922167/simple-webpage-change-or-button-removed-and-scraped-data-is-useless)

Though I tried to implement something similar below with no luck as the page is not structured as simply.  Any idea how I can cater for unequal data as data becomes uneven at random due to webpage.

Desired

```
 Azam FC v Mwenge    1.8    https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B1/C1/D13/E104/F16/S1/
 Western Sydney Wanderers v Melbourne City    2.87    https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B1/C1/D13/E101/F16/S1/
 Sydney FC v Newcastle Jets    1.53    https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B1/C1/D13/E101/F16/S1/
```

output looks like

```
 Azam FC v Mwenge    1.8    https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B1/C1/D13/E104/F16/S1/
 Western Sydney Wanderers v Melbourne City    1.53    https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B1/C1/D13/E101/F16/S1/
```

The 1.53 should not be for  Western Sydney but for Sydney FC

Script.py

```
 import collections
 import csv
 import time

 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
 driver.maximize_window()


 driver.get('https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AS/B1/')
 driver.get('https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AS/B1/')


 def page_counter():
     for x in range(1000):
         yield x

 count = page_counter()

 clickMe = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ('//div[div/div/text()="Main Lists"]//div[starts-with(@class, "sm-CouponLink_Label") and normalize-space()]'))))
 coupon_lables = [x.text for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[div/div/text()="Main Lists"]//div[starts-with(@class, "sm-CouponLink_Label") and normalize-space()]')]

 links = dict((next(count) + 1, e) for e in coupon_lables)
 desc_links = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(links.items(), reverse=True))
 for key, label in desc_links.items():
     driver.get('https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AS/B1/')
     clickMe = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ('//div[div/div/text()="Main Lists"]//div[starts-with(@class, "sm-CouponLink_Label") and normalize-space()]'))))
     driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//div[contains(text(), "' + label + '")]').click()

     groups = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div'
     xp_match_link = "//div//div[contains(@class, 'sl-CouponParticipantWithBookCloses_Name ')]"
     xp_bp1 = "//div[contains(@class, 'gl-Market_HasLabels')]/following-sibling::div[contains(@class, 'gl-Market_PWidth-12-3333')][1]//div[contains(@class, 'gl-ParticipantOddsOnly')]"

     try:
         # wait for the data to populate the tables
         wait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, (xp_bp1))))
         time.sleep(2)

         data = []
         for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(groups):
             try:
                 match_link = elem.find_element_by_xpath(xp_match_link) \
                     .get_attribute('href')
             except:
                 match_link = None

             try:
                 bp1 = elem.find_element_by_xpath(xp_bp1).text
             except:
                 bp1 = None

             data.append([bp1, match_link])
             # data.append([match_link, bp1, ba1, bp3, ba3])
         print(data)
         url1 = driver.current_url

         with open('C:\\daw.csv', 'a', newline='',
                   encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
             writer = csv.writer(outfile)
             for row in data:
                 writer.writerow(row)

     except TimeoutException as ex:
         pass
     except NoSuchElementException as ex:
         print(ex)
         break

 driver.close()
```

Comment: Could you provide the url of the page where this unstructured data is present?

Comment: @VikasOjha Here's one of pages where you can see data is not loaded right causing uneven data. https://www.bet365.com.au#/AC/B1/C1/D13/E40/F443/S1.  It seems to pop up every now and then not on each load

Comment: Well, here is the reason - the `groups` xpath gives 12 nodes whereas, `xp_match_link` gives 7 nodes. You will need to figure out a better way of writing these xpaths, so that they become consistent

Comment: I can't find a page that doesn't line up so it's hard to comment. You need to provide a page that shows the problem. One thing you could do is to count the number of matches and number of odds and then if the two numbers aren't equal, reload the page or don't scrape it or something.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you change the following xpath:

```
xp_match_link = "//div//div[contains(@class, 'sl-CouponParticipantWithBookCloses_NameContainer ')]"
```

Comment: The groups xpath seems perfectly right, as it is capturing two separate tables in the page

Comment: I am getting [1.80, None].  This is caused by groups xpath.  I could remove this entirely and scrape data normally but if a button is removed due to glitch which happens quite a bit then I get uneven data.

Comment: You could completely get rid of groups xpath and use the other ones directly. That would be better.

Comment: Sadly similar issue as .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922167/simple-webpage-change-or-button-removed-and-scraped-data-is-useless. There might be way to get element only if no blanks exists but cannot find much on this